creating named control sequences
I have a csv file with typical row content ["66,"primary description","description for LoF","myjpeg.jpg"] and I want to create a named macro for each row e.g for this row 'putImage66'
This will [eventually in a larger LuaLatex project] expand to an includegraphics, label, and caption sequence where the args for those are the other row elements.
I can successfully process the csv file with datatool, and get a alpha equivt for the numeric value , this is where I am at
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\newcommand\numberloop{}
% \expandafter to allow \newcommand\numbers{3456} \numberseq{\numbers}
\newcommand\numberseq[1]{\expandafter\numberloop#1\end}
\def\numberloop#1#2\end{%
   \numberstringnum{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\numberloop#2\end\fi}


\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,}




\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{images}{illustration.csv}

 % typical row content ["66,"primary description","description for LoF","myjpeg.jpg"]
 % intention to create series of macros named like 'insImagesixsix" with body to includegraphics, caption. and label
 
\DTLforeach*
    {images}% database label
    {\key=key,\captn=Caption,\ocaptn=otherCaption,\filnam=filename} % assignment
    { % Stuff to do at each iteration:
 
         \subsection*{\numberseq{\key}} \filnam % verifies number conversion 66-->sixsix

        \expandafter \newcommand %
        \expandafter {\csname  \insImage\numberseq{\key} \endcsname}%
        {{ place an image \filnam, and a caption \captn}}
        
        %\insImagesixsix
    }


\end{document}

cannot get my head around the \expandafter  commands
and the construction and evaluation of the \newcommand.
I have spent the last 48 hours around \edef, \csname and all their ilk.

It would be better to do this via \putImage{66}. Would such a user interface be sufficient?

@cfr you'd want \ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{\insImage\numberseq{\key}} (or else you get undefined behaviour if the built \csname is already defined).

i did consider @werner 's approach, I found datatool and used it to load and parse the file. The single format of macro pushes the row select and parsing into invocation time if I understand properly

@Skillmon  thanks. obviously wasn't really thinking that through.

If you're using LuaLaTeX you should probably do the parsing in Lua anyway.

Why do you need conversion of digits 66 -> sixsix?  Via \csname..\endcsname control sequence tokens can be constructed whose names contain digits/non-letters. An interface can be created which does \csname..\endcsname under the hood.

You must have \numberseq expandable. It is not true when you are using \numberstringnum from fmtcount.sty. It is better to make such macro directly using TeX primitives.
\documentclass{article}

\def\numberseq#1{\expandafter\numberseqA#1\end}
\def\numberseqA#1{\ifx\end#1\else \numberseqB#1\expandafter\numberseqA\fi}
\def\numberseqB#1{\ifcase#1 zero\or one\or two\or three\or four\or five\or 
                            six\or seven\or eight\or nine\fi}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{images}{illustration.csv}

 % typical row content ["66","primary description","description for LoF","myjpeg.jpg"]
 % intention to create series of macros named like 'insImagesixsix" with body to includegraphics, caption. and label

\DTLforeach*
    {images}% database label
    {\key=key,\captn=Caption,\ocaptn=otherCaption,\filnam=filename} % assignment
    { % Stuff to do at each iteration:
        \expandafter\edef\csname insImage\numberseq\key\endcsname{%
             place an image \filnam, and a caption \captn}
    }

\insImagesixsix % prints: place an image myjpeg.jpg, and a caption primary description

\end{document}


a noddy question : \numberseq must be expandable, but if I code e.g  \subsection*{\numberseq{\key}} \filnam % verifies number conversion 66-->sixsix it does evaluate. Q: what is the difference between expansion and evaluation? A million years ago I worked in macro assemblers , it never got this complicated

@aldobranti If you are using a macro inside \csname...\endcsname pair, then the macro have to return the sequence of characters which is used to construct the sequence name. The macro have to return sixsxix sequence in your example without using any unexpandable activities like \def, setting values etc. On the other hand, if you are printing sixsix, then TeX prints s, then an unexpandable activities (like \def) can be done, then print i, then other activities, then print x etc. If you are using \section{argument} you want to print it, no to get a sequence of characters.

@more exactly: the construction of control sequence have to be output from expand processor only (no main processor activities  may be performed). What is expand processor and main processor? It is described in my introduction text TeX in a Nutshell (page 4 below and page 5 above).

I don't think you gain much with \insImagesixsix over `\insImage{66}.
You can realize your objective with a property list.
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}
key,Caption,otherCaption,filename
"66","primary description","description for LoF","example-image.jpg"
"42","description","","example-image-a.jpg"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DTLsetseparator{,}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\processdatabase}{m}
 {
  \aldobranti_process:n {#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\insImage}{O{}m}
 {
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,#1]{\prop_item:Nn \g_aldobranti_images_prop {#2@filename}}
  \caption
   [
    \prop_item:Nn \g_aldobranti_images_prop {#2@lofcaption}
   ]
   {
    \prop_item:Nn \g_aldobranti_images_prop {#2@caption}
   }
  \end{figure}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__aldobranti_key_tl
\tl_new:N \l__aldobranti_caption_tl
\tl_new:N \l__aldobranti_lofcaption_tl
\tl_new:N \l__aldobranti_filename_tl
\prop_new:N \g_aldobranti_images_prop

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aldobranti_process:n
 {
  \DTLloaddb{images}{#1}
  \DTLforeach*{images}
   {
    \l__aldobranti_key_tl = key,
    \l__aldobranti_caption_tl = Caption,
    \l__aldobranti_lofcaption_tl = otherCaption,
    \l__aldobranti_filename_tl = filename
   }
   {
    \__aldobranti_put:nV {caption} \l__aldobranti_caption_tl
    \tl_if_blank:VTF \l__aldobranti_lofcaption_tl
     {
      \__aldobranti_put:nV {lofcaption} \l__aldobranti_caption_tl
     }
     {
      \__aldobranti_put:nV {lofcaption} \l__aldobranti_lofcaption_tl
     }
    \__aldobranti_put:nV {filename} \l__aldobranti_filename_tl
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aldobranti_put:nn
 {
  \prop_gput:Nen \g_aldobranti_images_prop { \l__aldobranti_key_tl @ #1 } {#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__aldobranti_put:nn {nV}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\processdatabase{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\insImage{66}

\insImage[width=4cm]{42}

\end{document}

The \insImage command has an optional argument for passing further keys to your \includegraphics command.
If the short caption is empty in the .csv file, it is replaced by the long one.


Since you're using LuaLaTeX you could as well move the file parsing and data storage into the Lua layer. The following is quick&dirty code to do just that.
I didn't add any additional options in this code, this is just the bare minimum.
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
66,"An example image showing a big A","An example image","example-image-a"
1,"A lovely duck","A duck","example-image-duck"
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
local img_data = {}
---Search the img_data for a given name and return the image data
---@param opt string additional options to use for includegraphics
---@param n string the name of the image in img_data
function printImg(opt, n)
  local d = img_data[n]
  if d then
    tex.print("\\includegraphics[" .. opt .. "]{" .. d.file .. "}"
      .. "\\caption[" .. d.lof .. "]{" .. d.cap .. "}")
  else
    tex.error("Unknown image " .. n)
  end
end

---Read a complete file to fill img_data
---@param f string the file path/name
function parsefile(f)
  local handle = io.open(f, "r")
  if not handle then
    tex.error("File not found")
    return
  end
  ---Read a single line in a file and add the image data to img_data
  ---@param l string the currently read line
  local function parseline(l)
    local fields = {l:match('^%s*([^,]-)%s*'
      .. string.rep(',%s*"%s*([^"]-)%s*"%s*',3))}
    if fields[1] then
      img_data[fields[1]] = { cap = fields[2], lof = fields[3], file = fields[4] }
    end
  end
  for l in handle:lines() do
    parseline(l)
  end
  handle:close()
end
\end{luacode}

\NewDocumentCommand\genImgData{m}{\directlua{parsefile(\luastring{#1})}}
\NewDocumentCommand\putImage{O{} m}
  {\directlua{printImg(\luastring{#1}, \luastring{#2})}}

\genImgData{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \putImage[width=.6\linewidth]{66}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \putImage[width=.6\linewidth]{1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



You can process retrieve the relevant information on an image-by-image basis using \DTLgetvalueforkey{<cmd>}{<key>}{<db name>}{<ref key>}{<ref value>}. This retrieves the value of <key> in <db name> where the corresponding <ref key> has value <ref value>, storing it in <cmd>.

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{illustration.csv}
key, Caption, otherCaption, filename
66, "An example image showing a big A", "An example image", "example-image-a"
1, "A lovely duck", "A duck", "example-image-duck"
12, "A square image", "", "example-image-1x1"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DTLloaddb
  %[]% Options
  {images}% db name
  {illustration.csv}% CSV

\NewDocumentCommand{\putImage}{ O{} m }{%
  \begin{figure}
    % \DTLgetvalueforkey{<cmd>}{<key>}{<db name>}{<ref key>}{<ref value>}
    \DTLgetvalueforkey{\Caption}{Caption}{images}{key}{#2}% Retrieve caption
    \DTLgetvalueforkey{\OtherCaption}{otherCaption}{images}{key}{#2}% Retrieve other caption
    % If no optional argument (\otherCaption), update it to match \Caption
    \DTLifstringeq*{\OtherCaption}{}{\let\OtherCaption\Caption}{}%
    \DTLgetvalueforkey{\Filename}{filename}{images}{key}{#2}% Retrieve filename
    \centering
    \includegraphics[#1]{\Filename}% Insert image
    \caption[\OtherCaption]{\Caption}% Insert caption
  \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\putImage[width=.3\linewidth]{66}

\putImage[height=3\baselineskip]{1}

\putImage[scale=0.5]{12}  

\end{document}

Many extensions are possible, including adding other keys to the options for \putImage that could be used for the \label, as an example.

I will bookmark DTLgetvalueforkey for future use __ I had problems initially understanding the dox

The following defines a rather low level parsing approach for your syntax without relying on datatools, though one could change the parsing step to also use that instead.
The generated syntax is using a single front end macro per read in file that takes the used image as a mandatory argument (like @Werner suggested). It also accepts an optional argument to set options of \includegraphics. Additionally four other keys are defined:

caption to use another caption than specified in the CSV
lof to use another LoF entry text
file to change the used file name (just for symmetry, doesn't make much sense)
label with this you can add a \label to your caption

For the key=value augmentation this uses expkv-cs (disclaimer: I'm the author of that package) since it's rather easy to set up a macro taking a small number of known keys with it (and super simple to just forward every unknown key using the ... notation).
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.csv}
66,"An example image showing a big A","An example image","example-image-a"
1,"A lovely duck","A duck","example-image-duck"
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \genImageMacro { m m }
  {
    \exp_args:Nc \NewExpandableDocumentCommand {#1} { O{} m }
      {
        \cs_if_exist_use:cTF { __aldobranti_img_ #1 _ \tl_trim_spaces:n {##2} :n }
          { {##1} }
          {
            \msg_expandable_error:nnnn { aldobranti } { unknown-image }
              {#1} {##2}
          }
      }
    \ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior {#2}
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_ior
      {
        \tl_if_blank:nF {##1}
          {
            \__aldobranti_split_line:nw {#1} ##1 \q_stop
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__aldobranti_split_line:nw #1 #2,"#3","#4","#5" #6\q_stop
  {
    \cs_new:cpx { __aldobranti_img_ #1 _ \tl_trim_spaces:n {#2} :n } ##1
      {
        \exp_not:N \__aldobranti_image:n
          {
             caption = { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#3} }
            ,lof = { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#4} }
            ,file = { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#5} }
            ,##1
          }
      }
  }
\ekvcSplit \__aldobranti_image:n
  {
     caption = {}
    ,lof = {}
    ,file = {}
    ,V:~ label = \c_novalue_tl
    ,...
  }
  {
    \includegraphics [ {#5} ] {#3}
    \caption [ {#2} ] { #1 \IfValueT {#4} { \label {#4} } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\genImageMacro{putImage}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  % adding a label is easy via a key
  \putImage[label=fig:66, width=.6\linewidth]{66}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  % you can overwrite the LoF entry using the lof-key. You could also overwrite
  % the caption with the caption-key (and even change the used image file)
  \putImage[lof=The second duck, page=2, width=.6\linewidth]{1}
\end{figure}

See \ref{fig:66}.

\end{document}



OP here. The environment for this is a much larger LuaLatex project. I would not be confident to move this [looks like Latex3] into the larger project. Will edit the question

@aldobranti you realise you are using expl3 already?

@aldobranti what @cfr says. If your document uses fontspec for instance you're well past the "no LaTeX3" point.

Oh! thanks, red face moment!

further to do some thing about that U have asked question [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/731648/latex-returner-seeks-recommendations-for-books]

You can use \csname..\endcsname for producing control sequence tokens whose names do not only contain letters but also contain non-letters, e.g., digits.
Therefore with the examples below \numberseq-conversion is omitted.
If you prefer cumbersome vintage code, you can combine usage of \expandafter with exchanging macro arguments.
\begin{filecontents*}{MYillustration.csv}
66,"An example image showing a big A","An example image","example-image-a"
1,"A lovely duck","A duck","example-image-duck"
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\stopromannumeral{\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%===============================================================================
%%\ApplyToArgUndedinedDefined
%%  {<tokens to prepend to {<Argument>} in case <Argument> forms the name of a 
%%    control sequence token which is undefined or equal to \relax>}%
%%  {<tokens to prepend to {<Argument>} in case <Argument> forms the name of a
%%    control sequence token which is defined and not equal to \relax>}%
%%  {<Argument>}%
%%
%%  The first argument can be used for calling a macro which does
%%  default-action ordoes deliver error-message where the <Argument> can occur.
\newcommand\ApplyToArgUndedinedDefined[3]{\@ifundefined{#3}{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
\newcommand\UndefinedError[1]{%
  \@latex@error
    {%
      There is no control sequence defined whose name can be constructed from %
      tokens \detokenize{"#1"}%
    }%
    \@ehc
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb[%
            noheader=true, 
            keys={key,Caption,otherCaption,filename}%
          ]{images}{MYillustration.csv}


\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*
    {images}% database label
    {\key=key,\captn=Caption,\ocaptn=otherCaption,\filnam=filename} % assignment
    {%Stuff to do at each iteration:
      \subsection*{\key}%
      \filnam
      %----------------------------------------------------------------
      % Define the macro by combining \expandafter with flipping macro
      % arguments around via \PassFirstToSecond or \Exchange:
      \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral
        \Exchange{.}{%
          \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\filnam}{%
            \Exchange{.\\This is the filename: }{%
              \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\ocaptn}{%
                \Exchange{.\\This is the other caption: }{%
                  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\captn}{%
                    \Exchange{.\\This is the caption: }{%
                      \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\key}{%
                        \stopromannumeral This is the key: %
                      }%
                    }%
                  }%
                }%
              }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }{%
        \CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{insImage\key}%
      }%
      %----------------------------------------------------------------
      %\begingroup\CsNameToCsToken\endgroup\show{insImage\key}%
      \par
      \bigskip
      \noindent
      \ApplyToArgUndedinedDefined\UndefinedError\CsNameToCsToken{insImage\key}%
    }%

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\noindent Usage of macros:

\bigskip

\noindent
\ApplyToArgUndedinedDefined\UndefinedError\CsNameToCsToken{insImage1}

\bigskip

\noindent
\ApplyToArgUndedinedDefined\UndefinedError\CsNameToCsToken{insImage66}

% Trigger error message:
%\ApplyToArgUndedinedDefined\UndefinedError\CsNameToCsToken{insImage77}

\end{document}


You can define your \insImage⟨key⟩-macros to expand to four brace-groups containing the data of the datafields of the data-record in question. These beace-groups can denote four undelimited arguments.
For using your \insImage⟨key⟩-macros you can define an interface \UseDataRecordMacro which takes three arguments:

First argument: Tokens to prepend to the third argument in case the tokens of the third argument do not denote the name of a macro:; this can be used for delivering an error-essage or a default-value.
Second argument: Tokens to prepend to the toplevel expansion of that macro in case the tokens of the third argument denote the name of a macro. The last of these tokens is intended to be a macro which processes four arguments denoting the four datafields of a record of the database.
Third argument: Should denote the name of a macro delivering four undelimited arguments coming from a record of the database.

\begin{filecontents*}{MYillustration.csv}
66,"An example image showing a big A","An example image","example-image-a"
1,"A lovely duck","A duck","example-image-duck"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \PassFirstToSecond, \Exchange,
%%    \stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\stopromannumeral{\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument denotes name of macro:
%% (Only with macros the \meaning contains the sequence ->) 
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherCsNameDenotesDefinedMacro[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}{\UD@secondoftwo}{%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \CsNameToCsToken
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\stopromannumeral
      \expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherMacro\meaning{#1}->%
    }{\UD@secondoftwo}{\UD@firstoftwo}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@@CheckWhetherMacro{\long\def\UD@@CheckWhetherMacro#1->{}}%
%%=============================================================================
%%\UseDataRecordMacro
%%  {<tokens to prepend to the third argument in case the tokens of the
%%    third argument do not denote the name of a macro; this can be used for
%%    delivering an error-message or a default-value>}%
%%  {<tokens to prepend to the toplevel expansion of that macro in case the
%%    tokens of the third argument denote the name of a macro; the last of
%%    these tokens is intended to be a macro which processes four arguments
%%    denoting the four data-fields of a record of the database>}%
%%  {<third argument: tokens denoting the/expanding to the name of a macro
%%    delivering four undelimited arguments coming from a record of the
%%    database>}%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UseDataRecordMacro[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherCsNameDenotesDefinedMacro{#3}{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname#3\endcsname}{#2}%
  }{%
    #1{#3}%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UndefinedError[1]{%
  \@latex@error
    {%
      There is no control sequence defined whose name can be constructed %
      from tokens \detokenize{"#1"}%
    }%
    \@ehc
}%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\PrintAllFourFieldsOfDataRecord[4]{%
  key: #1\\Caption: #2\\otherCaption: #3\\filename: #4%
}%
\newcommand\IncludegraphicsDatarecord[4]{%
  \begin{figure}%
  \begin{center}%
  \includegraphics{#4}\\%
  (The primary key of this image in the database is: #1)%
  \caption[#3]{#2}%
  \end{center}%
  \end{figure}%  
}%
\newcommand\GetKey[4]{#1}%
\newcommand\GetCaption[4]{#2}%
\newcommand\GetOtherCaption[4]{#3}%
\newcommand\GetFilename[4]{#4}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb[%
            noheader=true, 
            keys={key,Caption,otherCaption,filename}%
          ]{images}{MYillustration.csv}


\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*
    {images}% database label
    {\key=key,\captn=Caption,\ocaptn=otherCaption,\filnam=filename} % assignment
    {% Stuff to do at each iteration:
      %% ----------------------------------------------------------------
      %% Define the macro by combining \expandafter with flipping macro
      %% arguments around via \PassFirstToSecond or \Exchange:
      \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral
        \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\filnam}{%
          \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\ocaptn}{%
            \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\captn}{%
              \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\key}{%
                \stopromannumeral
              }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }{%
        \CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{insImage\key}%
      }%
      %% ----------------------------------------------------------------
      %% Show the meaning of the defined macro on the console:
      %\begingroup\CsNameToCsToken\endgroup\show{insImage\key}%
      %% ----------------------------------------------------------------
      %% Have LaTeX typeset some stuff into the pdf-file;
      \subsection*{\key}%
      \filnam
      \par
      \smallskip
      \noindent Macro \texttt{\CsNameToCsToken\string{insImage\key}} defined as\\
      \texttt{\CsNameToCsToken\meaning{insImage\key}}%
      \par
      \smallskip
      \noindent Applying \texttt{\string\PrintAllFourFieldsOfDataRecord} yields:\\
      \UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{\PrintAllFourFieldsOfDataRecord}{insImage\key}%
    }%

\bigskip
\hrule
\listoffigures
\bigskip
\hrule
\noindent \strut Usage of macros:

\bigskip

\noindent
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{\PrintAllFourFieldsOfDataRecord}{insImage1}%

\noindent
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{Key: \GetKey}{insImage1}\\%
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{Caption: \GetCaption}{insImage1}\\%
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{Other caption: \GetOtherCaption}{insImage1}\\%
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{Filename: \GetFilename}{insImage1}%

\bigskip

\noindent
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{\PrintAllFourFieldsOfDataRecord}{insImage66}%

\noindent
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{Key: \GetKey}{insImage66}\\%
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{Caption: \GetCaption}{insImage66}\\%
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{Other caption: \GetOtherCaption}{insImage66}\\%
\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{Filename: \GetFilename}{insImage66}%

\clearpage

\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{\IncludegraphicsDatarecord}{insImage1}%

\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{\IncludegraphicsDatarecord}{insImage66}%

% Trigger error message:
%\UseDataRecordMacro{\UndefinedError}{\IncludegraphicsDatarecord}{insImage77}%

\end{document}


