latex returner seeks recommendations for books
Recent requests for help here have been gratefully received but indicate that my TeX / LaTeX knowledge is very ancient.
My bookshelf has

'TeX for the Impatient'/Abrahams 1994
'Joy of TeX'/Spivak 1986
'LaTeX Notes'/Shultis 1990

I was a grad math student about 50 years ago, I had a brief rerun with a outfit who ran TeX for a custom app to print IPR info in the mid 90's. Now as an artist I must be the IT lead and book designer for my publisher on my own artwork books. Bah!
I think I need to know what the last years of development have done and not to be phased by newer styles of syntax. Of the books that I kept Shultis' LaTeX notes has been most useful: perhaps a cookbook style would probably be best but all suggestions are welcome

Welcome back! :-) Are you familiar with the posting What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner? By the way, the resources suggested in the answers to that posting are not just for beginners. If you're willing to consult a book, I can personally recommend George Grätzer's "More Math into LaTeX" (5th ed 2016). It looks like there's a 6th ed of this book, published just this year. Note that the book title has changed, a bit confusingly, from "More Math into LaTeX" to "Text and Math into LaTeX".

A lot of the newer syntax is aimed at back end developers.  I think the best approach to TeX hasn't really changed all that much since it first came out: attempt to do what you want to do, and when you get stuck, then look up how to do it.

„The Latex Companion“, 3rd edition. Book in 2 parts, ~700 pages each. Less a textbook, at least a tour through proven and latest developments, as you asked, beside expl3. Explains, gives background information, shortcomings and package based solutions. You can read it cover to cover or on demand.Preview: https://www.latex-project.org/news/2023/03/17/TLC3/ It will make you spending more time on https://ctan.org/ to inspect relevant package manuals.
